# e(fx)clipse code completion isn't working

Tags: java, efxclipse

could you give me any advice how to fix that, please?

Recently I installed e(fx)clipse, but code completion when you type a dot, isn't working. Google didn't help.

**Edit:** Ctrl+Space works well, But dot with dropdown list of options is not working. (when you type a dot and see which methods can work with some instance)

**Edit2:** Also, when I type imports like:
import org.openqa.selenium.*; -----> autocompletion is not working here, even if I type that exactly under the line like that (in my old projects) - so it's not the issue of a project settings.

[Installation details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCR51.jpg)

**Edit3:** Content assist looks fine... but the issue still present.

**Edit4:** After doing this:

---

To clarify Alex's answer.

I had the same issue of being unable to get auto-complete with my JavaFX CSS. My fix was add the JavaFX SDK to the library list. To do that:

Go to Project | Properties
Select Java Build Path in the tree
Click on the Libraries tab
Click the Add Library... button
Choose JavaFX SDK
Click Next then Finish
Click Apply
Click OK

---

e(fx)clipse failed to start at all. (only splash screen appears for a milisecond)

**Edit5:** Java version is:

$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_71"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_71-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.71-b15, mixed mode, sharing)

**Edit6:** Funny, but after I reinstalled e(fx)clipse, it still fails to start. The same issue with 1-millisecond splash screen and nothing more..

**Edit7:** Reinstalled JDK + several times reinstalled e(fx)clipse: 2 times version 4.5.2 and one time the version 4.6RC4a - - - in all the cases just 1-millisecond splash screen appears and nothing more... yep, and before these reinstallations I cleaned Windows registry.

**Edit8:** I just used Java Mission Control and recorded timeframe during which I tried to open e(fx)clipse, and I noticed this thing:

[From Java Mission Control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBQmh.jpg)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eclipse autocomplete not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21746294/eclipse-autocomplete-not-working)

Comment: Possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27130489/ide-efxclipse-not-working-properly .

Comment: It's not a duplicate, they have another issue (Ctrl + Space is not working), I read their methods, it didn't help.

Comment: If you try to use a JavaFX method, does it work, or it gives you an exception?

Comment: I only tried this code (exactly):  https://github.com/Gravituss/JavaPractice01/blob/master/J011JavaFxExample.java  and it worked without exceptions